# How to fix QFile open error (unknown error) even though the file exists?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfile

I am trying to open and read a `map.dat` file using `QFile` interface, but it won't open that file even though it does exist in the directory.

- I have tried `fopen`, `ifstream` in C++, but they keep telling me the file does not exist even I have added it into resource folder (`.qrc`). Then I turn to `QFile` interface, the problem remains. This is a directory problem, I now compromise and use absolute(not the best practice) path and now the file existence problem is solved.
- Now it still cannot open the file, I use interface's member function to see what are the error code and error message, and I got `0` and `Unkown Error` which is not a useful information.

I am using:

- MacOS Mojave 10.14.2.
- Qt 5.11.3.
- Compiler: clang_64bit

```
QFile mapDat("/Users/myname/projectname/file.dat");
if (!mapDat.exists()){
    qDebug() << "not exist";
}

QString errMsg;
QFileDevice::FileError err = QFileDevice::NoError;
if (!mapDat.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) | QFile::Text){
    errMsg = mapDat.errorString();
    err = mapDat.error();
    qDebug() << "could not open it" << err << errMsg;
    return;
}

QTextStream in(&mapDat);
QString mText = in.readAll();
qDebug() << mText;
mapDat.close();
```

I expect `qDebug() << mText` to give me something in the console, but it doesn't.

The output is:

> could not open it 0 "Unknown error"

which is from the `qDebug()` line within the if statement.

Comment: 0 should be no error, not unknown error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is wrong:

```
if (!mapDat.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) | QFile::Text)
```

This will try to open the file in read-only mode. The result of that is negated (`!`), and then ORed with `QFile::Text` (which is != 0). So the condition will always be true.

You have a simple typo (misplaced parenthesis):

```
if (!mapDat.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
                                 //  ^ Bitwise OR of flags for mapDat.open call
```