# Been writing a notepad clone with QT6 c++, but every time I save the file, it creates the file empty without the text from TextEdit;

Tags: c++, qt, save, qtwidgets

So I am writing the code for a notepad clone which I hope would evolve into a final draft clone in further updates, and I am using it as a tool to learn C++ and QT as I am still Quite a beginner with the langauge.

I have implemented a save function into the application, which when pressed should take the text written in the Textedit widget and write it into a file, but what seems to happen is that when I call that function it creates said file but leaves it empty without adding the text into it

this is my code

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSave_as_triggered()
{
    QString File_name = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save File as");
    QFile File(File_name);
    if(!File.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) | QFile::Text) {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Save warning", "Error: File Did not save properly" + File.errorString());
        return;
    }
    current_file = File_name;
    setWindowTitle(File_name);
    QTextStream out(&File);
    QString writing = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    out << writing;
    File.flush();
    File.close();
}
```

here is the entire cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
,     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete UI;
}


void MainWindow::on_actionNew_triggered()
{
    current_file.clear();
    ui->textEdit->setText(QString());
}


void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{


}


void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
QString File_name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open the 
File");
 QFile File(File_name);
 current_file = File_name;
 if(!File.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)){
     QMessageBox::warning(this,"warning", "Error, File Could not 
open");
     return;
 }
 setWindowTitle(File_name);
 QTextStream in(&File);
 QString Writing = in.readAll();
 ui->textEdit->setText(Writing);
 File.close();
}


void MainWindow::on_actionSave_as_triggered()
{
    QString File_name = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save File as");
    QFile File(File_name);
    if(File.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)) {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Save warning", "Error: File Did not save properly" + File.errorString());
        return;
    }
    current_file = File_name;
    setWindowTitle(File_name);
    QTextStream out(&File);
    QString writing = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    out << writing;
    File.flush();
    File.close();
}
```

edit: Tried removing, File.flush and .close but I still get the unknown error

Comment: Is `File.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) | QFile::Text` what you meant to write?

Comment: I don't think so,  I added the "!" because I wanted to print out the error if the file does not open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix QFile open error (unknown error) even the file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464877/how-to-fix-qfile-open-error-unknown-error-even-the-file-exists)

Comment: I fixed the typo but it still gives me an unknown error

Comment: Then please share a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because what you provided works when that typo is fixed.

Comment: I shared the rest of my code if that would help find the bug

Comment: Your condition is wrong again, put `!` back, unknown error because there is no error.

Comment: oh I didn't see that typo at all! that solved it! thank youu

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
out.flush();
```

instead of

```
File.flush();
```

(or just drop it altogether).

And you don't need `File.close()`, [it is automatic for files](https://codebrowser.dev/data/symbol.html?root=../qt5/&ref=_ZN11QFileDeviceD1Ev).

The way you've coded it, the file gets closed before the `QTextStream` writes data to it.